# how to decrese the size of button to a small size inside cell of datagrid view button column with out changing other column cells width

Tags: c#, winforms, button, datagridview

Hi i have data gridview button column its displaying button fine .... but it occupies entire cell in every row like below figure .. buy is the column name ...... i want to resize the button to oval shape ......

how can i do this......and this is my code for button column code....

```
       DataGridViewButtonColumn column = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();
        daatgridview1.Columns.Add(column);
        column.Resizable = DataGridViewTriState.True;
        column.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Popup;
        column.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Green;
        column.Text = "Buy";
        column.HeaderText = "Buy";
        column.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = true;
        column.Name = "btnbuy";
```

would any one pls help on this one ......

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the column style´d `Padding` property to a padding that fits. It will increase the distance between your button and the grid´s grid lines.

"Gets or sets the space between the edge of a DataGridViewCell and its content." -- http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcellstyle.padding.aspx

Be sure to set the style on the correct "layer" so you don´t end up setting this for each cell individually.

Answer (score 0):

i have not understood your question about oval shape, do you mean you want button to be in standart style in winforms? if so, change your FlatStyle into .Standart:

column.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Standard;

Comment: sorry thats not what i want how to decrese the size of button to a small size in cell of datagrid view this is my question ...

Comment: okey, i've looked your code and opened a project for it; but i can not succeed what you desire ... :( i've a question either, how can you add click event to this button ?

Comment: Ask that click event question as a separate question, please. When you post it, I am 99% sure SO will suggest related questions of which some are dupes to the one you´d post.